# Is it possible to write HERE flexible-polyline directly into Postgis?

Tags: routes, postgis, here-api

Is there a Possibility to directly **write a HERE flexible-polyline into my Postgis/Postgres Database** without Decoding, converting to Text and then make a Geometry using ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(...) ? I am afraid that there is no possiblilty (other than with Google-encoded-Polyline). Or is there something to use?

Background: I am testing the HERE-API for routing. I have found the Java-source to Decode the resulting Polyline from Github: https://github.com/heremaps/flexible-polyline. Therefore I can read the coordinates from this flexxible-polyline-String

- flexible-Polyline: `BG8_9j7Cy11iXsBlBoBrEnBrErJrJzF3DnGvC7GnBvHoBjNkI7BrE7GvR7BjDrEvH_E3I_EvHvCrE3SnajNrTjIjNvHjN7G_OvHjSnGnQ_EzP_E_TrEnVrErYjDvWrEvgB7BnLjD_TvCjXjDvgB5D9qB`
- this results in the coordinates: (47.774718 / 12.102489) (47.77474 / 12.10247) (47.77476 / 12.1024) (47.77474 / 12.10233) .... (in the South of Germany)
- or as Postgis-Request: `ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(12.102489 47.774718, 12.10247 47.77474, 12.1024 47.77476, 12.10233...`

My Request is:

- https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&return=polyline,summary,travelSummary&routingMode=short&departureTime=2021-02-10T06:40:00&apiKey=******&origin=47.77494541091896,12.103053452705371&destination=47.77202596545944,12.095115520523986

But now I wanted to convert this Point-List to Postgis. I hoped to use an existing function, e.g. **ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline** from Postgis. Unfortunately this does not return valid results as it is based on the Google encoding/decoding algorythm. Results from ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline are (which clearly shows that it is a huge difference between these Polyline-compressions):

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKT(ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline('BG8_9j7Cy11iXsBlBoBrEnBrErJr.....
--Result:
SRID=4326;LINESTRING(0.00004 -0.00002,0.0042 -0.00015,0.00422 -0.00405,0.00431 -0.00104,0.0048 ...
```

Is there some way e.g. using a multiplier to get this geometry from the HERE-String?

Comment: there seems to be not answer ... and probably it really does not work.

Never mind - i just finished programming it by creating an LatLong-String and making a LINESTRING and write it into Postgis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I couldn't find an answer or a working solution, I wrote as I hoped not to ... My results are the following:

1. Java Jackson-Parser

   ```
   ObjectMapper oJacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   IOUtils.copy(oRespIputStream, oStringWriter, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()) );
   JsonNode oJsonNode = oJacksonObjectMapper.readTree(sJsonString);
   ```
2. RoutingHereSection.java

   ```
   @JsonProperty("polyline")
   private String polylineString;
   private List<LatLngZ> listeLatLonCoords; 
   private String listeLatLonCoordsAsPostgisString;
   ```
3. PolylineEncoderDecoder.java (from Github) added Method:

   ```
   public String getKoordinatenMitSpaceFuerPostgis() {
      return ""+ lng +" "+ lat;   // => not lat/lng for Postgis
   }
   ```
4. parse the Coordinate-String

   ```
     this.listeLatLonCoords = PolylineEncoderDecoder.decode( this.polylineString );
   ```
5. Loop to create LINESTRING

   ```
           this.listeLatLonCoordsAsPostgisString = "";
           if (this.getListeLatLonCoordsAnzahl()>0) {
               String sGeom = "LINESTRING(";
               for (int ii=0; ii<listeLatLonCoords.size();ii++) {
                   if (ii>0) { sGeom +=", "; }
                   sGeom += listeLatLonCoords.get(ii).getKoordinatenMitSpaceFuerPostgis();
               }
               sGeom += ")";
               this.listeLatLonCoordsAsPostgisString = sGeom;
           }
   ```
6. INSERT into using Jdbc

   ```
   String sSql = "INSERT INTO mytable ST_GeomFromText( ? ,4326) "
   Object[] oParam = new Object[] { oSectionReturn.getListeLatLonCoordsAsPostgisString() } 
   int[] oType = new int[] { java.sql.Types.VARCHAR }
   getJdbcTemplate().execute( sSql )
   ```

that's it ... more or less.